# Stock price predictions of keras multilayer LSTM model converge to a constant value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression, lstm

[image]I've made a multilayer LSTM model that uses regression to predict next frame's values of the data. The model finishes after 20 epochs. I then get some predictions and compare them to my ground truth values. As you can see them in the picture above, predictions converge to a constant value. I don't know why this happens.
Here is my model so far:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.python.keras.initializers import RandomUniform

init = RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval= 0.05)

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(kernel_initializer=init, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, units=800, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.2, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]) ))
model.add(LSTM(kernel_initializer=init, activation='relu', return_sequences=False, units=500, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.2 ))

model.add(Dense(1024, activation='linear', kernel_initializer=init))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', kernel_initializer= 'normal'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop' )
model.summary()
```

**EDIT1:**
I decreased epochs from 20 to 3. results are as follows:
[image: prediction results after 3 epochs.]

By comparing 2 pictures, I can conclude that when the number of epochs increases, the predictions are more likely to converge to some specific value which is around -0.1.

Comment: LSTMs can´t find patterns, if there are no patterns. Stock prediction in very short intervals is close to random data.

Comment: Whenever I use just one layer of LSTM, instead of two, the model works very nice and detects patterns. So this shows that LSTM **can** find pattern. But adding one more LSTM layer causes the odd outcome. Maybe somehow weights are not updated well or LSTM units cannot save weights. I don't know.

Comment: Ok, so probably your gradient is vanishing. Have you tried to take a look in tensorboard at the histograms and distributions?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Not yet. But as soon as I successfully create tensorboard results or try to implement some methods to overcome gradient vanishing, I'll inform you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after trying different number of `LSTM` units and different types of architectures, I realized that the current number of `LSTM` units causes the model to learns so slowly and 20 epochs were not sufficient for such huge model.For each layer, I changed the number of LSTM units to 64 and also removed `Dense(1024)`layer and increased the number of epochs from 20 to 400 and results were incredibly close to the ground truth values. **I should mention that the dataset used in the new model was different from the former one because I encountered some problems with that dataset** . here is the new model:

```
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform, glorot_normal, RandomUniform

init = glorot_normal(seed=None)
init1 = RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05)
optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units=64, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, 
               input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]), 
               return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer=init))

model.add(LSTM(units=64, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, 
               return_sequences=False, kernel_initializer=init))


model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', kernel_initializer= init1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer )
model.summary()
```

you can see the predictions here:
[image]

It's still not the best model, but at least outperformed the former one.
If you have any further recommendation on how to improve it, it'll be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The performance you're getting is far beyond what is expected from a price prediction model. It is so good I think there is something wrong with your model, or how you evaluate it. Might you have shifted the values by one time lag? It is very common to make LSTM time series predictions which do nothing but output the previous value, and then mistakenly shift your output in time when comparing with the result. Here is a very similar case I once discovered: https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

Comment: Surprisingly, I used that link as a basis and created my model based on it. Suppose my data frame is comprised of time series of 4 column data, namely x1, x2, x3 and y. I re framed my dataset as follows: I shifted just the X_input (in this example x1, x2, x3) by 20 time lags. By doing so, I made a new dataframe which has 3*20 columns (20 columns related to x1: x1_t-20, x1_t-19, ..., x1_t-1 , 20 columns related to x2: x2_t-20, x2_t-19, ..., x2_t-1 and 20 columns related to x3: x3_t-20, x3_t-19, ..., x3_t-1). Then did a reshape operation for X_input:(n_samples, 60) ==> (n_samples, 20, 3)

Comment: And then used the new data frame to predict y_t based on this reshaped data. I used the same approach in [House Prices: Advanced Regression Techniques](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques) and the mse became around 0.5 which was not accurate enough compared to the other competitors (ranked 4500th/4800)

Comment: I believe I should post a new question because I feel I have some great misunderstanding about my current modelling framework.

Comment: You can also consider posting at stats.stackexchange.com or datascience.stackexchange.com. I think they will be able to help with they "why" of your questions, and not just the "how".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try.